# Does the proficiency bonus stay the same at each level in a tier or am I supposed to add to it at each level?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-advancement, proficiency

I'm looking at the Character Advancement table on pg15 of the 5e Players Handbook. It shows that levels 1-4 have a +2 proficiency bonus each, levels 5-8 are +3 each, etc. I don't know if it is telling me to increase my proficiency bonus by that much at each level or if it is an absolute value.

In other words, suppose I level up to 6. Is my proficiency bonus 3 or 14?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It gives the total bonus, not the additional bonus per level.

> In other words, suppose I level up to 6. Is my proficiency bonus 3 or 14?

It is 3

Page 57 of the System   Reference   Document    5.1 gives an example:

> Your  proficiency bonus   is  always  based   on  your    total    character  level,  as  shown   in  the Character    Advancement    table,  not your    level   in  a   particular  class.  For example,    if  you are a   fighter 3/rogue 2,  you have    the proficiency bonus   of  a   5th-level   character,  which   is +3.